# iCal4j ics file not importing to outlook 2010

Tags: outlook-2010, icalendar, ical4j

I'm having trouble importing an ics file via the 'internet calendars' option in outlook. The file is produced I believe by a java applet. When I open the ics file directly within outlook 2010 it works fine i.e. click on the link and open the downloaded file with outlook. I've also validated it online with the validator mentioned in some stack overflow posts.

However when I subscribe to the link via internet calendars I get the following error:

"The file "calendar" is not a valid Internet Calendar file"

I haven't been able to work out what's going wrong here and the error message isn't particularly helpful.

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me this is not a programming question; in which case, it belongs on [SU].

Comment: Fair point. My bad.

Reposted here: http://superuser.com/questions/492197/ical4j-ics-file-not-importing-to-outlook-2010

Comment: No problem. BTW, if you want one of your questions migrated, you can flag them for moderator attention, and ask for migration. Anyway, welcome to StackExchange, and good luck getting a useful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved on this thread:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/forums/forum/368291/topic/6062163/index/page/1

Unfortunately, I only have access to the applet link and not any of the code used to produce the ics file itself so unless I can find a way to automatically parse the file and add in the line METHOD:PUBLISH I won't be able to add the feed in outlook.

Comment: Try contacting the developer, it shouldn't be too hard for them to add the extra line when generating the file.

Answer (score 0):

While this does appear to be a non-technical question it may be related to the iCalendar implementation of Outlook. Perhaps you could post the sample ICS data to the ical4j forums to see if there is something obvious that Outlook doesn't like.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/forums/forum/368291